# How to have jProfiler record method invocation parameters?

Tags: java, jprofiler

I'm trying to run jProfiler in offline mode, and have configured a specific trigger to create a recording and save a snapshot.  This is great in that it generates a list of profiled method calls under my trigger conditions, but it only tracks method invocation, and does not keep track of parameter values during invocation.

Is there any way to keep the method parameter details as part of the snapshot so I can better identify exactly which method call is being problematic?  My current trigger defn is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Split methods" feature for this purpose. Based on the parameters of a method you can create a string that is used to group the cal tree below it:

[image]